# Renaming Library project doesnt update reference to Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have download one project from https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview, it is containing library and a sample. I tried to rename the library by refactoring and build it successfully as library_dragdrop. Now when I am trying to run the sample that is "Launcher" after modify the reference of the library so it is not letting be build the project.

Updated Reference of library as :

Right click on Launcher project --> Android --->  Library and remove previous and added new from project dropdown and it is showing green but when I am cleaning and build so it goes onto previous reference as library and showing me all red.

I tried copying the package from library to "Launcher sample" but although it resolved many errors but now R cannot be resolved and still can't run the sample project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Project-> Clean Project?

Comment: right click project->android tools-> fix project properties

Answer (score 0):

Check all you .xml files, not only your layouts. Just a slightly error can make big problems. The editor might not show where the error is, so look thoroughly!